# Can I replace the non-sliding glass unit in a window?

Tags: repair, windows, diy-vs-pro

I have a Ply Gem horizontal slider window that I installed 2 yrs ago and the glass on the non-sliding window portion cracked. Can I just purchase another same size window (71.5 in. x 35.5 in.) and swap the glass unit myself? I want to just replace the 1/2 of the window that's cracked - not the whole window. Looks like the double pane window part comes out as an assy - just want to make sure I can do this myself - the glass shop said they can do it but it's 3X the price of a whole new window from HD. The orange is the crack area - the blue area is what I want to swap out from a new window.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Yes you can replace the glass. IF you can figure out how to remove it.  There are different methods of securing glass to a frame.  If you give better, closer pics of the glass at the frame it may become evident of how it can be removed.

Comment: Usually glass does not suddenly crack without reason.  Building stress(being to tight in the opening) or being hit are the two common reasons.